# Firebase hosting shows welcome screen

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I've been trying to deploy a React CRUD web-app on firebase however I get "Firebase Hosting Setup Complete" screen whenever I deploy. I have followed documents and  after I "firebase init" I choose "Firestore" and "Hosting" from CLI menu and setup the public directory as "build" and didn't make any other changes on initialization but I keep getting Firebase Hosting Page. 
I don't know why it's not working. I have followed every step on documents. Is there any other way to host my app on Firebase?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meofoNuK3vo <-- I rewatch this video everytime I need to use firebase hosting. Should do the trick hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Were there any error messages with `firebase deploy`? Try to deploy a html file and check whether it works.

Also make sure to check using a private window.

Comment: I didn't get any error messages after "firebase deploy". Database, firestore everything compiles successfully and valid. I have also tried to open the link in incognito mode, yet I am still getting the "Firebase Hosting Setup Complete" page.

Comment: Please check your firebase.json file. Make sure you have set `public` directory as needed. If you point to a empty location, firebase cli might create a default `index.html` for you!